# LXC container clone has no network and SSH stopped

Tags: linux-networking, lxc, clone

I was having this networking problem with LXC containers
(question and answer here:[bridging LXC containers to host network with different IP range](https://serverfault.com/questions/641728/bridging-lxc-containers-to-host-network-with-different-ip-range/642109#642109))

and if I have found a solution, I still have not found the reason of the problem:

I started with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 Server, and installed LXC
The lxcbr0 bridge is created automatically, and a newly created LXC container, which IP was set properly, has network access and SSH running: I can ssh to it, I can ping the container from the outside and ping the world from inside. All is good.

Now, **when I CLONE** this new container, change the IP of the clone, it starts fine, but **SSH is NOT running on start up**, i have to start it manually.
**I also cannot get networking to work** from the inside: the lxcbr0 bridge can be ping'd but that is as far as it goes; everything else is unreachable.

However if I CREATE a second container, change the IP as before, all is normal like for the  first one, so somehow in CLONING my container something is going wrong with initializations.

Any suggestion about what could be going on in cloning?

PS: I use the lxc web panel to clone, but I confirmed that the command line behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to stop the container first?
i had this issue, too.

stop the blue print container, clone it, change the ip, mac, directories, etc.

then try to start the containers.

note: do not use the lxc web panel as it is buggy and does not behave as wanted.